# Custom Layout in Notification bar Android

Tags: android

I created a custom notification layout in android. But I want to change the content of the notification layout programmatically.

For example in the notification layout I have WebView and when I press a button in the activity that creates a Notification I want to load custom URL in the WebView to do that I have to type following code in java:

```
WebView wv = findViewById(R.id.webView);
wv.loadUrl("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

but I can't I tried with LayoutInflater still failed any ideas

Comment: Do you mean a custom view for notification created with [Notification.Builder.setCustomContentView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setCustomContentView(android.widget.RemoteViews))? Because You can inflate only a limited set of basic widgets listed [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews).

Comment: yes I use setCustomContentView and pass RemoteViews object